# JavaScript Site with working examples

Tags: javascript, web

I saw a website a little while ago that had columns for JavaScript/HTML/CSS and below it had what the actual code would look like.  Kind of like jsFiddle, but it had user examples and demos.  Does anyone know the name of this site?  I can't find it anywhere!  THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely talking about [CodePen](http://codepen.io/), which is a site with an active community and many demos viewable right on the page with the source code.

Comment: Ah!  That's it!  Thank you!

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer so the community knows there is an accepted answer.